# Collection Wrapper as JSON List?

Tags: jackson

I need to wrap a `List<Something>` in a DTO (say, `Wrapper`) so that some custom annotations work as expected. I end up with this:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private List<Something> list;

    @CustomAnnotationsHere
    public List<Something> getList() { ... }

    public void setList(List<Something> list) { ... }
}
```

However, this makes Jackson serialize/deserialize the `Wrapper` object as

```
{
  "list": [...]
}
```

which, IMHO, is too verbose and unnecessarily complex. Is there any way to have Jackson serialize/deserialize this `Wrapper` object as a list (the value of the `list` field)?

I would swear I once came across an annotation-based way of achieving this, but at the moment I can't recall where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `@JsonValue` to the field for serialization, and a single-argument constructor for deserialization?